# C#,Winforms: how to hide controls and display contents of these controls in tabular format while printing?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I hava a form for sales invoice.I have used datagridview,textboxes,combo boxes in the form.I have a print button,when i click on print button i want to generate the same from in the bill format.& want to hide all the controls & want to display like labels in tabular format.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say about the "Tabular Format"!. what's your means of tabular format?

Comment: for Tabular Format you must be learn at-least one of the Reporting Tool's.Such as Crystal Report, Stimul Report,etc.If you want print in un-tabular format you need work with the PrintDocument object in .Net Framework

Answer (score 0):

Winforms won't be able to help you there. There is no magic bullet to do that. 
It would be far simpler to create a report in the same format using some reporting tool.

That said, if you really must go this weird way, you need to make custom controls inheriting from all the controls you used. Override the OnPrint method, and change the control styles as you want there.